# /etc/fstab if one mount fails nothing gets mounted?

Tags: nfs, fstab, cifs

In our `fstab` we have multiple cifs and nfs shares that get mounted. Sometimes if a cifs share is down and not mountable, then nothing else in the `fstab` gets mounted.

Is there a way to "skip" over unmountable drives and make sure the rest of the `fstab` gets mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Implement those external resources as autofs mounts.  This will allow fstab to complete and the automounter, a kernel-space function, will be able to negotiate the instantiation of the external links as needed and if available.

You may need to add something to your os to get it setup.  On

> Centos/Redhat: yum install autofs
>
> Ubuntu: apt-get install autofs

Then follow your distro's setup guides for configuring.

Note:
The `--ghost` option will keep the "expected" base directory path in place on the mount location.  Some applications get unpleasant if the base mount path is missing and is then created on the fly.

Also, if the windows shares being mounted have been secured to not use SMB 1.0, be sure to use the argument `vers=2\.1` in your mapping string to specify that the mount should be attempted at SMB 2.1, otherwise long timeouts and failures to mount will occur.

Comment: I will look into this.